# PHP SDK v3 reporting issues

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I have downloaded the IPP PHP SDK and am wondering how to make the REST calls for reporting. I am trying to make any REST call and it doesn't seem to work..

I have used the `AccountFindAll.php` as an example for calling the REST API. I either get nothing back, which makes me think if I am even calling it right, or there is no data returned. I have received an error though for the `AgedPayables` report saying permission denied. The `AccountsFindAll.php` example does work and brings me back what I want but it is using some kind of query format.

I would like to use the REST API but I can't get it to work. If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be so appreciated.

Here is my code:

```php
<?php

require_once('config.php');

require_once(PATH_SDK_ROOT . 'Core/ServiceContext.php');
require_once(PATH_SDK_ROOT . 'DataService/DataService.php');
require_once(PATH_SDK_ROOT . 'PlatformService/PlatformService.php');
require_once(PATH_SDK_ROOT . 'Utility/Configuration/ConfigurationManager.php');

//Specify QBO or QBD
$serviceType = IntuitServicesType::QBO;

// Get App Config
$realmId = ConfigurationManager::AppSettings('RealmID');
if (!$realmId)
    exit("Please add realm to App.Config before running this sample.\n");

/*
$accessToken = $_REQUEST['accessToken'];
$tokenSecret = $_REQUEST['tokenSecret'];
$realmId = $_REQUEST['realmId'];
*/

$realmId = ConfigurationManager::AppSettings('RealmID');

// Prep Service Context
$requestValidator = new OAuthRequestValidator(ConfigurationManager::AppSettings('AccessToken'),
                                              ConfigurationManager::AppSettings('AccessTokenSecret'),
                                              ConfigurationManager::AppSettings('ConsumerKey'),
                                              ConfigurationManager::AppSettings('ConsumerSecret'));

$serviceContext = new ServiceContext($realmId, $serviceType, $requestValidator);
if (!$serviceContext)
    exit("Problem while initializing ServiceContext.\n");

//$httpsUri = "company/".$realmId."/reports/AgedPayables";  //?date_macro=Today
$httpsUri = 'company/'.$realmId.'/companyinfo/'.$realmId;
//$httpsUri = 'company/'.$realmId.'/query';
//$httpsPostBody = 'select * from CompanyInfo startPosition 0 maxResults 500';
$httpsPostBody = NULL;

$httpsContentType = CoreConstants::CONTENTTYPE_APPLICATIONTEXT;

$requestParameters = new RequestParameters($httpsUri, 'GET', $httpsContentType, NULL);
$restRequestHandler = new SyncRestHandler($serviceContext);

list($responseCode, $responseBody) = $restRequestHandler->GetResponse($requestParameters, $httpsPostBody, NULL);

$parsedResponseBody = NULL;
try {
    $responseXmlObj = simplexml_load_string($responseBody);
    if ($responseXmlObj && $responseXmlObj->QueryResponse)
    {
        $responseSerializer = CoreHelper::GetSerializer($serviceContext, false);
        $parsedResponseBody = $responseSerializer->Deserialize($responseXmlObj->QueryResponse->asXML(), FALSE);                                                                 
    }
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    IdsExceptionManager::HandleException($e);
}       

print_r($parsedResponseBody);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer:

https://developer.intuit.com/blog/2014/03/25/the-quickbooks-online-reports-api-has-arrived

PHP SDK does not support Reports at this time.

Comment: PHP does support JSON. http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.json.php. Also in the link you sent me. The first two comments are as follows:  Is the reponse JSON only or is XML available? The response is JSON only.

Comment: I meant the SDK. Corrected the statement above.

Comment: Please check the comment from Jarred on the same post-The .Net and Java SDKs have been updated to support the new report APIs as well. https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits

Answer (score 0):

I get an XML response to report queries.

Comment: You might be getting the response but that the engineering team has confirmed that right now fully tested/supported data is in JSON format.